# Moderator meta tags don't show red in chat

Tags: bug, tags, chat

Using `[meta-tag:status-completed]` or any other mod tag shows it red: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

However, in chat, this isn't the case:

[image]

Comment: It's also squared in the corners, is this because the chat is "shared"?